# SharePoint MOSS Alternate Access Mappings

Tags: sharepoint, moss, alternate-access-mappings

In SharePoint MOSS I have a site at http://ourintranet/ I've now added a new entry to the Alternate Access Mapping for the domain http://www.mydomain.com pointing at this site. When I now type this in I get redirected to http://ourintranet/ and the visible url changes.

Is there a way to have this work where by the domain remains as http://www.mydomain.com?

All the best

Comment: What do your AAM's look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to extend the Web Application @ http://ourintranet and specify www.mydomain.com as a host header. This will create a new IIS Web site responding to the specified host header. Extending a Web Application also requires you to select the zone for which the extension should be applied.

Comment: I had this link in my SP favourites which describes what Lars is saying very well:
http://elczara.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!554EC06D366AC9D5!502.entry

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What zone did you add it as? If you put it in the extranet zone it should work?